# Close votes in the review queues

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

This image sums it up:

[image]

Here we have an item in the review queue ([link to review](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/close/1707), [link to question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/141/tricks-for-opening-very-tight-jars))

You can see that we have 6 people voted - 3 for leave open and 3 for close. I voted to Leave Open because I believe it is clear what it's asking.

If the review queue is that subjective this site still has a lot of problems - and this is not a one off (click the image to link to review):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know the answers, but I'm hoping there is a solution for this site... We need a way to know, definitively what should be closed and what shouldn't, and *we need it quickly*.

Comment: Maybe pinging the people that did this, to see their reasoning.

Comment: Possibly, but I think it still shows a big problem - one that I hadn't seen before...

Comment: I think that it shows that people have a lot of different reasons for close and open.  They aren't up to date with what is going on. I think that people need to get on Meta and understand what is going on.

Comment: What side are you on(close or open)? I think that you should update your post with reasons why you feel such a way, you could possibly use examples from the scope.

Comment: I don't feel either way. I'm just bringing it to the attention of the people - I'm no expert on what should be done here.

Comment: But you voted on the content. So I think you should add your reasoning. No matter, though.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicates the dirty hands ones as I feel they are logically answered by simply using common sense and applying the same principal as the "parent" solution.